# What antennas do I use with an Intel 5300 NIC?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, network-adapter, antenna

I am working on a project using [this tool](https://dhalperi.github.io/linux-80211n-csitool/) to collect channel state information from a Wi-Fi connection. The tool was specifically designed for the Intel 5300 NIC, so I ordered the card online. The NIC has three male connectors for antennas.

See the top of this picture:

[image: Image of the Intel 5300 NIC]

I've tried doing research online, but I haven't been able to find any information on what antenna types/models are compatible with the Intel 5300 NIC, or how to purchase them. How would I be able to get antennas to use with this NIC?

I am using [this Mini PCIe to PCIe adapter](https://www.startech.com/Cards-Adapters/Slot-Extension/PCI-Express-to-Mini-PCI-Express-Card-Adapter~PEX2MPEX) (StarTech PCI Express to Mini PCI Express Card Adapter PEX2MPEX) to connect the NIC to a PCIe slot inside a Dell Optiplex 3020 Small Form Factor. I am connecting to a [TP-Link AC1750 router](https://www.tp-link.com/us/home-networking/wifi-router/archer-c7/), which will be a subnet of the university network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those connectors look like [Hirose U.FL male connectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hirose_U.FL):

> “U.FL connectors are commonly used in applications where space is of critical concern, most often Mini PCI cards for laptop computers. U.FL connectors are commonly used inside laptops and embedded systems to connect the Wi-Fi antenna to a Mini PCI card. Another common use is connecting GPS antennas.”

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Would [these antennas](https://www.amazon.com/Highfine-Wireless-Extension-Bulkhead-Repeater/dp/B01GMBUS8O) work with my NIC? It looks like one end of the pigtail cable is U.FL, and the other end is RP-SMA, which would then connect to the black antenna.

Comment: @asdf60367134 Seems like it.